# Как в моей программе исправить почти бесконечный цикл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если я ввожу число 1 или 100, то программа прекрасно работает, например, я ввел число 1, компьютер предположил, что я ввел 10, и предлагает мне выбрать между больше и меньше. Я пишу "меньше", и так, пока не угадает, т.е. диапазон ,несомненно, сокращается с "1-100" до "1-10", но, если мое число - 50, комп предлагает 51, я пишу "меньше" - комп предлагает, допустим, 32, я пишу больше, комп предлагает уже 82, т.е. этот цикл превращается в практически бесконечный, если взять диапазон побольше. Когда мое число 50, комп предлагает 51, как мне сделать так, чтобы, комп именной в этой "сессии" "игры" не предлагал уже более 51?

```
import random
print ("Добро пожаловать в игру 'Загадай число'!")
print ("Вы должны выбрать любое число в диапазоне от 1 до 100,")
print ("компьютер попытается отгадать заданное Вами число, используя минимальное количество попыток.")

the_number = int(input("Введите число от 1 до 100: "))
tries = 1
PC_number = random.randint(1, 100)
print (PC_number)
while PC_number != the_number:
    if the_number != PC_number:
        print ("Загаданное число больше или меньше предложенного?")
        value = input ()
    if value == "больше":
        PC_number = random.randint(PC_number, 100)
    elif value == "меньше":
        PC_number = random.randint(1, PC_number)
    print (PC_number)
    tries += 1
print ("Ваше число - ", PC_number ,"Компьютер угадал ваше число с", tries ,"попытки")
input("Нажмите Enter, чтобы выйти.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранять попытки в переменные и вызывать random.randint() с этими значениями, а не с 1 и 100.

```
if value == "больше":
    min_guess = PC_number
elif value == "меньше":
    max_guess = PC_number
PC_number = random.randint(min_guess+1, max_guess-1)
print (PC_number)
```

Comment: Поправил немного, опечатка была.

Comment: А можно тут вопрос в комментариях задать по этой же программе, только кое в чём другом? Или нужно создать новый вопрос?

Comment: И ещё немного поправил (оптимизировал).

Comment: Лучше другой вопрос.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Mg3Zq2b у меня вот такая вот ошибочка выходит. Хотя с табуляцией вроде всё правильно, перепроверил

Comment: Это означает, что для отступа использован символ табуляции вместо пробелов или наоборот. Нужно удалить отступ до начала строки и вбить его заново.

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk и вот чтоб такого не было, лучше используйте интегрированные среды разработки, PyCharm например, он такие проблемы сам ловит и фиксит

Comment: так, я теперь исправил эту табуляцию, теперь запускается код, но у меня подозрение, что 17 строка уехала вправо на 4 пробела, и возможно из-за этого появилось это: https://imgur.com/a/0yO1bGp И если я 4 пробела убираю, то опять ошибку выдает как на тех скринах.

Comment: Конечно, уехала. надо убрать эти четыре лишние пробела.

Comment: на последнем скриншоте нужно строчки 18 и 19 внести в цикл (увеличить отступ).